# How do we specify the quality of Sound Juicer copied CD tracks?

Tags: lubuntu, music, 18.10, cd, sound-juicer

In Sound Juicer's Preferences the user can specify with which filetype to copy the CD data, but how do you specify the desired bit rate, i.e. audio quality?

Comment: You mean Sound juicer? Please update your question if needed, and then you find the answer here https://help.gnome.org/users/sound-juicer/stable/preferences.html.en

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to my titular error and sharing these clarifications with me, but that page does not directly answer my question: Am I to infer that there is no need to specify the bit rate of the file format, e.g. that ogg and mp4 will automatically make it as small as possible? (I am accustomed to iTunes or perhaps Windows Media Player in which one selects a bit rate (or amount of compression?) from a drop-down menu for a given file type. I was thinking this feature would or should be included in any popular CD data-extraction software.) Incidentally, Ogg Opus is on my PC, not WAV.

Comment: I always used Sound Juicer to rip to FLAC, for best quality. But then to play on my mp3 player that would not read FLAC used sound converter to convert to mp3. Last did this several years ago, but back then conversion & save to player was faster than conversion & then copy to player.

Comment: I do not have Sound Juicer installed anymore, but the link indicates you must change/add sound profiles in gstreamer in order to use these in Sound Juicer. Indeed, no friendly interface to change encoding parameters is available in Sound Juicer. You have to go in the basement to change these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default quality settings in Sound Juicer have always been flaky. In the early days, there was just a checkmark on what format you wanted to use without any possibility to change encoding parameters. Later, one was allowed to edit arcane gstreamer lines. An edit button in the preferences dialog allowed to edit Sound Juicer profiles. Currently, that possibility appears to be gone, leaving the original author of Sound Juicer to comment on a Reddit thread in which someone complained that removing the codec-editing option made it [a Useless Piece of Crap](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2t29br/sound_juicer_cd_ripper_is_now_officially_a/cnvz78d/).

So probably the advice is, as given for many years on many fora, to move on and find a better sound ripper.