# Setting Sound Juicer prferences

Tags: sound-juicer

I want to rip a CD to MP3s but I cannot find the preferences in Sound Juicer. In the topbar there is the entry "Sound Juicer" but there is no "edit" or "preferences" under it. Lame and ubuntu-restricted-extras are installed.

[image]

Edit: Someone has suggested another question about configuring Sound Juicer might help but this eanswer requires the preferences menu which are still missing. So that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we specify the quality of Sound Juicer copied CD tracks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107319/how-do-we-specify-the-quality-of-sound-juicer-copied-cd-tracks)

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Sound Juicer. I installed K3b and can change the preferences in the usual manner. Ripping MP3s with K3b is quick and easy.